# Nested strcuture

Tags: c++

I need a perspective on the following from optimization point of view :

I have a structure with some fields :

```
struct cmp {
   uint64_t count;
   uint8_t  var;
   uint64_t val_1;
   uint16_t val_2;
};
```

Some of the fields that i have a can be moved to another structure :

```
struct Field {
   uint8_t  var;
   uint64_t val_1;
   uint16_t val_2;
};
```

From code readability this is a better option :

```
struct cmp {
    uint64_t count;
    Field    field;
};
```

I use the cmp structure in the following ways :

1. Initialize members by using parametrized c'tor. as the members become more the number of arguments increases and its looks ugly.
2. Use cmp structure as part of stl data containers.

Having nested structures impact optimization of code ? if yes how ?

what will be the better approach using them ?

Comment: Since you are using C++, why can't you implement the structs as classes and use inheritance?

Comment: @Lundin One reason: it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @millimoose How can you tell? The structs have fuzzy names and could be used for anything. There is no telling from this question what they are actually used for.

Comment: @Lundin Nonetheless I don't see an *is-a* relationship here, as much as composition. I'm taking the fact the OP hasn't included any behaviour as weak evidence of there not being any - this means there isn't really much of a reason to use inheritance and thus polymorphism. I'd also use classes when they're meant to be opaque and defined mostly by their behaviour (that is when you're actually doing data-hiding), structs to ferry related values around.

Comment: @millimoose You don't see one because it is impossible to tell with the poorly chosen variable names given. Hence my question for clarification to the OP.

Comment: There is no is-a relationship here. No inheritance required whatsoever.

Comment: @Lundin My point is that *at best*, it doesn't matter whatsoever, as far as this question is concerned, whether or not the OP uses a struct or class. Since it's a question about performance (or rather microoptimisation), not design, you're going off on a tangent unless using classes / inheritance would be "faster". (Which I'm guessing wouldn't since once again the object layout should be similar.) If this was tagged as [tag:c] and not [tag:c++] the question would be just as valid and the answer would probably be the same.

Comment: I think Lundin's suggestion of `struct cmp : public Field` is just a suggestion for shortening the code, not for optimizing.

Comment: @Lundin if it is impossible to tell then how can one suggest inheritance? I could suggest to use an `std::tuple`, but I won't, because there isn't enough info. Concerning `struct` and `class`, they are the same in C++ anyway.

Comment: i think the aim of question got sidelined with this unnecessary inheritance stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is here:

> From code readability this is a better option.

This is the option you should take.

Profile afterwards, and make changes afterwards if necessary. Although I highly doubt it. As-is, the objects should have the same layout.

Comment: Agree, the memory layout should be the same. what about optimization when accessing field ?

Comment: @Dexter: Since the layout is the same none.

Answer (score 1):

It wont impact performance. The structures have the same layout in memory and the compiler knows exactly at what offset all members are since you are not using pointers. Theres no difference between the two in terms of performance

Comment: What about alignment and padding? In the case where 64 bit values (and I assume a 64 bit o/s) are used I`m not 100 percent sure of the exact size of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to think about is padding and memory alignment. I`m not 100% sure about how the presence of a 64 bit int would affect this so if you provided the size of your struct, via sizeof(cmp) it would give more information to work with. If you have an array of cmp it will make a difference.

Also, as previously said, the more readable option is better, in my humble opinion.